# MySQL: Is it best practice to check whether some column is NULL by `NOT ISNULL(column_name)`?

Tags: mysql, database-design, best-practices

Given the following schema, my question is that since I have already added the `NOT NULL` to `IsBanned`, would I have to check whether it is not null using the syntax `NOT ISNULL(IsBanned)`? And what's the best practice to do the same if I didn't add `NOT NULL`?

```
CREATE TABLE Viewer (
    AccountID varchar(25),
    IsBanned boolean                NOT NULL
                                    DEFAULT 0,
    ...
    CHECK                           (NOT ISNULL(isBanned)),
);
```

Comment: Can you not just use OR `CHECK (Twitter LIKE "https://twitter.com/%" OR Twitter IS NULL)`

Comment: @Charlieface: Do you mean this post or another? And I don't understand the grammar of your sentence.

Comment: You can use `OR` inside a check constraint, so you can just check if the value is either null or it matches the `LIKE`. I was going off your comment below where it seems you want nulls, but yeah, if it's `NOT NULL` then obviously you don't need to check that

Comment: @Charlieface: Thanks for your clarification!

Answer (score 1):

How many different values do you need?  It sounds like you need only "true" and "false".  If so, declare the column to be `NOT NULL`.  There is no need for a `NULL` check if it is declared `NOT NULL`.  The `NOT NULL` performs that `CHECK`.

If you need yes/no/maybe or yes/no/don't-know-yet, etc, then you could declare it to be `NULL` (which simply means that it has an extra possible setting, namely `NULL`).

Comment: I want to make check like *"if it is null then ok go for it, while if your value if not null then I want to check the string value is in format ..."*, e.g.
```CHECK (IFNULL(TRUE, (Twitter LIKE "https://twitter.com/%"))),```
but this line doesn't work, could you help?

Comment: `CHECK ( Twitter LIKE 'https://twitter.com/%' )` is fine for checking `Twitter` column. But how is that related to whether `isBanned` is null or not?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: I meant if the user don't know the value (so `NULL` given) then I won't check it, while if the user give say `https://twit_bla.com/sample` then I should block it because it should be in format `https://twitter.com/%`.

Comment: @Rainning - I would not trust MySQL's implementation of `CHECK` to be very robust.  I recommend you use app code to check the data before inserting it.

Comment: If the value is null, then it passes the CHECK constraint

Comment: But you haven't answered my question: why your question asks about a not nullable isBanned column and your comments are all about a nullable varchar Twitter column?